# OpenVPN RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Below is my vpn configuration (it worked for first time) and not working post that.

```
remote xxxx-vpn.com 1195 udp
ns-cert-type server
pull
tls-client
persist-key
fragment 1430
pkcs12 pkcs.p12
dev tun
persist-tun
comp-lzo adaptive
mssfix 1430
resolv-retry infinite
mute 20
mute-replay-warnings
link-mtu 1476
keepalive 5 30
nobind
connect-retry-max 1
log-append /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
script-security 2
up "/bin/bash -c \"/usr/bin/resolvectl dns tun0 10.30.30.10 && /usr/bin/resolvectl domain tun0 xxx-lab.com\""
```

and my log file

```
OPTIONS IMPORT: WARNING: peer-id set, but link-mtu fixed by config - reducing tun-mtu to 1347, expect MTU problems
TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
/sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1419
/sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.10.10.22 peer 10.10.10.21
/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/resolvectl dns tun0 10.30.30.10 && /usr/bin/resolvectl domain tun0 xxx-lab.com tun0 1419 1476 10.10.10.22 10.10.10.21 init
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Fri Nov  6 12:12:00 2020 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 2
Fri Nov  6 12:12:00 2020 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
```

From the error it seems like there are some duplicate entries `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`
But I am not sure how to fix this as I am new to Ubuntu Linux.

How can I fix my configuration/which file to edit/delete to fix this issue? I did reboot multiple times and still issue persists